# Need help adding types to event bus methods

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to subscribe to an event, but TSC gives me an error ([ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/AQ4SwOwFwUwJwGYEMDGNgFEBuNrAN4BQooA2gNYwCeAXMAM5RyQDmAunY8xCwNzGgAvgJCRYiVOmy4oACSQQAJgBt4BEaAAUMHNDrToASjpYA9mEX8SwkmPjI0wAMKmICMC3UkQEJAFsYTiZWKyFCDQQAVwgUKDBXYATtXSgAOX9AhmCeABpgHRl5JVU4fRSilXhDL28UV3pTVQA6ZVMWZJl0gLyC6AqSww1hCOjY+IhgOrcPfrVNKfcWOhdplmqib0n6xpgWtvnXRcHrcJJXTQByBY8LvOuWWbhDIA)).

```
interface Event {
  [key: string]: string;
}

interface EventHandler {
  (event: Event): void;
}

interface Config {
  name: string;
}

function on (eventName: string, eventHandler: EventHandler) {
  console.log(eventName, eventHandler)
}

function configHandler (config: Config) {
  console.log(config)
}

on('config', configHandler) // TSC ERROR HERE
```

**Error**

> Argument of type '(config: Config) => void' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'EventHandler'.   Types of parameters 'config' and
> 'event' are incompatible.
> Property 'name' is missing in type 'Event' but required in type 'Config'.

**What would be your fix for this issue?**

Comment: Are you mixing up 'config' and 'event'? A `ConfigHandler` is not an `EventHandler` like the error describes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because

```js
on('config', configHandler) // TSC ERROR HERE
```

expects as a second argument `EventHandler`. Arguments of `EventHandler` and `configHandler` are not assignable to each other.

```js
declare var config: Config;
declare var ev: Event;

config = ev // error
ev = config // error
```

Btw, `Event` is defined in TS globals. It is a built-in type.

Are you sure you want to extend it by index signature?

In order to make it work, you should extend `Event` type by `Config`:

```js
interface Event extends Config {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

Anyway, this seems to be not type safe.

Take a look on this example:

```js
const enum Events {
  foo = "foo",
  bar = "bar",
  baz = "baz",
}

/**
 * Single sourse of true
 */
interface EventMap {
  [Events.foo]: { foo: number };
  [Events.bar]: { bar: string };
  [Events.baz]: { baz: string[] };
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type EmitRecord = {
  [P in keyof EventMap]: (name: P, data: EventMap[P]) => void;
};

type ListenRecord = {
  [P in keyof EventMap]: (
    name: P,
    callback: (arg: EventMap[P]) => void
  ) => void;
};

type MakeOverloadings<T> = UnionToIntersection<Values<T>>;

type Emit = MakeOverloadings<EmitRecord>;
type Listen = MakeOverloadings<ListenRecord>;

const emit: Emit = <T,>(name: string, data: T) => {};

emit(Events.bar, { bar: "1" });
emit(Events.baz, { baz: ["1"] });
emit("unimplemented", { foo: 2 }); // expected error

const listen: Listen = (name: string, callback: (arg: any) => void) => {};

listen(Events.baz, (arg /* { baz: string[] } */) => {});
listen(Events.bar, (arg /* { bar: string } */) => {});
```

Above example is much safer.

[Here](https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe), in my blog, you can find more explanation